# I want to define loss function for 3-best classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm design a classification model.

I have a problem, there are many categories which has similar features. 
I think best options is re-generate category hierarchy, but those are fixed.

So, I focused on 3-best accuracy, instead of 1-best accuracy.

I want to defined a loss function for 3-best accuracy.

I don't care where is the answer in position 1 - 3.

Is there any good loss function for that? of How can I define it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Show some data? An example maybe?

Comment: I know this was asked almost 18 months ago. I'm currently attempting/hoping to find info on the same thing. One idea to try: formulate your problem from multi-class to multi-label. So for instead of having the label be a one hot vector with only one class on, you'd have that vector be all zeros, but the three classes that could be on top three would have 0.33. Not sure how practical that is, especially when classes don't particularly overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy` for calculating accuracy.
 But this one is accuracy metric. I don't think there is any inbuilt top_k loss function in TensorFlow or Keras as of now.
 A loss function should be differentiable to work with gradient based learning methods. While `top_k` is not a differentiable function. Just like accuracy metric.
 Hence it can be used as accuracy metric but not as learning objective. So you won't find any inbuilt method for this, however there are other research papers aiming to solve this problems. You might want to have a look at [Learning with Average Top-k Loss](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07595) and [Smooth Loss Functions for Deep Top-k Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08826).

Answer (score -1):

you can use any of the below

top_k_categorical_accuracy

```
keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=3)
```

sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy

```
keras.metrics.sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=3)
```

Comment: I already that metric as a accuracy metric. But I don't know how i can use that as a loss function. not accuracy metric.